# Money-Rails Gem with Rails 4 - Instance Currencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

Im trying to use monetise in my Rails 4 app (with money-rails gem).

How do you allow a user to submit a number dollars only? When I input 100 I get $1 instead of $100.

In my model, I have:

```
monetize :participation_cost_pennies, with_model_currency: :participation_cost_currency
```

I am using instance currencies, so users select the relevant currency. My table has columns for participation cost, participation cost pennies and participation cost currency.

In my form, I have:

```
   <%= par.select :participation_cost_currency,
                             options_for_select(major_currencies(Money::Currency.table)),
                             label: false,
                             prompt: "Select your costs currency" %>

            <%= par.input :participation_cost, label: false, placeholder: 'Whole numbers only', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 250px; margin-top: 20px', class: 'response-project'} %>
```

In my view, I have:

```
   <%= money_without_cents_and_with_symbol @project.scope.participant.participation_cost  %>
```

By replacing 'participation cost pennies' with participation cost in the form, I get the number to show as a whole number without cents I now get $10,000 when i enter 100 (so the reverse problem in that it is adding 2 00s to the end of my input.

Comment: This sounds like a strong-params issue. Have you white-listed your params correctly in the controller?

Comment: Hi Sir Bertly, I have white listed the params for the participant model in each of the participants and projects controllers. I haven't added them to my scopes controller. I don't think I need them there because scope is nested within projects. Question updated with white listed params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems, you use `price` column inside the database and ask users to input exactly same input. This two different setters/getters. Try the following:

```
# add migration
rename_column :products, :price, :price_cents


# set monetize for this field inside the model
class Product
  monetize :price_cents
end

# inside form use .price instead of .price_cents method
f.text_field :price
```

In this case user set price in dollars and it will be automatically converted to the cents to store it inside `price_cents` field.

Answer (score 1):

In the `money-rails` gem, prices are saved [in cents](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#usage-example), so a `price` of 10 will be saved as 1000 `price_cents`. This is made on purpose to [avoid floating point rounding errors](https://github.com/Rubymoney/money#features).

To display the right price(without the cents), just call the `price` method on your object and it will display the correct non-cents price

Comment: How do I write the helper function?

Comment: Multiply the input by 10.

Comment: For those who find themselves here, do not convert the input by yourself, the gem already does that for you, just populate the `price` field and have `monetize :price_cents` on your model

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have **price_cents** column in your table.
You can try this code to convert dollar amount to cents before monitize:

```
monetize :price_cents
before_save :dollars_to_cents

def dollars_to_cents
    #convert dollar to cents
    self.price_cents = self.price_cents * 100 
end
```